# Mod_jk unmounting all requests to except of one site

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, httpd.conf, mod-jk

I have a few sites that need to be unmounted `/myUrl/.*.pdf` except `/myUrl/apple.pdf`. 
I originally wrote

```
JkUnmount /myUrl/.*.pdf worker1 
JkMount /myUrl/apple.pdf worker1
```

Then I realized JkUnmount will actually overwrite JkMount. Then I created a `worker2` for `JkMount /myUrl/apple.pdf worker2` but it is kind of expensive to add a new worker just for a simple site.
May anyone tell me how I could actually unmount all `/myUrl/.*.pdf` except `/myUrl/apple.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `JKMount` with `Location` or `LocationMatch` elements. This way you could even avoid use of `JKUnmount`:

```
<Location "/myUrl/apple.pdf">
    JKMount worker1
</Location>
```

This way only `/myUrl/apple.pdf` would be mounted and not any other pdf. If more complex selection should be made, you could use `LocationMatch` instead and provide a matching regular expression